# Query for multiple post types does not work

Tags: custom-post-types

I'd like my frontpage to display a list of my lastest blog posts merged with my latest "Products" custom post type posts.

From the documentation i gather this should work:

```
query_posts( array('post_type' => array('post', 'product') ) );
while (have_posts()) : the_post();
   the_title();
   the_excerpt();
endwhile;
```

But that turns a weird list, made of pages !

Note that I've put it outside the loop.

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

almost!
when doing it outside of the loop, you have to reset the query as in:

```
wp_reset_query();
```

Answer (score 3):

I would use a `new WP_Query`. Using `query_posts` is intended for the main loop only.

[When should you use WP_Query vs query_posts() vs get_posts()?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1753/when-should-you-use-wp-query-vs-query-posts-vs-get-posts)